# Nginx + FastCGI uses Management records? If not, then what?

Tags: c#, nginx, mono, fastcgi

I am writing a FastCGI application interface library in C#/Mono, running on a plain-'ol Linux box (Vagrant and/or EC2), using Nginx as the web server. I am trying to make my implementation comply with the [FastCGI 1.0 spec](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/22). As such I am prepared to receive a FCGI_GET_VALUES record, and respond with FCGI_GET_VALUES_RESULT. However, my experience is that Nginx FastCGI is not sending this. So, the questions I am trying to answer:

(1) OK, the web server's not *required* to send FCGI_GET_VALUES, it's optional. So, has it fallen out of use? Do other FastCGI server implementations still use this or not? Is there a way to configure Nginx FastCGI to enable it?

(2) Three defined config values go back to the web server in the FCGI_GET_VALUES_RESULT record: max concurrent transport connections the app will accept; max concurrent requests the app will accept; whether the app multiplexes connections. Lacking FCGI_GET_VALUES, what alternative methods, if any, exist to communicate or configure Nginx's FastCGI module with such settings?

Answer (score 1):

1) I recently went on a search for an open source web server with support for FastCGI management messages. I skimmed the source code of several very quickly, including nginx. The only one that looked like it had code to send FCGI_GET_VALUES was OpenLiteSpeed. I didn't get round to testing it before giving up on FastCGI I'm afraid, and it didn't look like it actually paid any attention to the values it received.

2) I'll cover what I know about each parameter individually:

FCGI_MAX_CONNS: Don't think there's any way to directly specify this in nginx. Maybe you could do something with http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html

OpenLiteSpeed has an option to limit the number of connections to a fastcgi server.

FCGI_MPXS_CONNS and FCGI_MAX_REQS: nginx doesn't support multiplexing FastCGI over a single connection. I couldn't find a web server that did.

For reference, I skimmed through the source code of these web servers, and none of them look like they send FCGI_GET_VALUES:

apache2 (mod_fastcgi, mod_fcgi, mod_proxy_fcgi), caudium, monkey, hiawatha, jetty, lighttpd, nginx, cherokee

Some of them did process FCGI_GET_VALUES_RESULT though.